# Upgrade pip inside a venv

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I have 2 versions of Python on my computer (3.7 on PATH, and 3.6 **not on PATH**)

I can create virtual environments for both versions using either:

- `python -m venv /path/to/venv` (for a 3.7 one)
- `/path/to/python36 -m venv /path/to/venv` (for a 3.6 one)

However, the following command `/path/to/venv/exe -m pip install --upgrade pip` only works on my Python 3.7 environments and not my 3.6 ones (I'm guessing because the system sees Python 3.7 as my default version because it is the only one in my PATH). How can I fix this?

I can't use `pyvenv` or `virtualenv` or modules like those.

Comment: Have you read from the [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#compatibility) that "The current version of pip works on: CPython 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and latest PyPy3." ? <-- There is no Python 3.6. The [`--upgrade`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/?highlight=upgrade#cmdoption-U) command tries to upgrade to newest available version (which is not supported on Python 3.6).

Comment: Not sure though if the "newest available" means really "newest", or if it should try to install the newest supported version. What version of pip you have on your python 3.6 venv? It seems that the newest supported pip version for Python 3.6 is [pip 21.3.1](https://pypi.org/project/pip/21.3.1/)

Comment: search inside the `/path/to/venv/exe` the pip command instead of python. or run directly the python36 interpreter. maybe this call the right pip

Comment: @np8 I think you are correct. My Python 3.7 venvs are on pip 22.1, and my Python 3.6 venvs are on pip 21.3, which looks ok with the docs. I guess I'll have an update message for nothing everytime I do a ```pip list``` (which is totally fine by me).

Comment: I think that the update message is a bug. It should not notify users on python 3.6 to try to update to a version that is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

The [`--upgrade`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/?highlight=upgrade#cmdoption-U) flag tries to update to the *newest available version*, which in case of Python 3.6 is pip [21.3.1](https://pypi.org/project/pip/21.3.1/). Pip [22.0](https://pypi.org/project/pip/22.0/) already requires Python>=3.7.

See also: [pip release history in PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#history).